# How to make a struct in `sol_storage` layout in `stylus`?

Tags: arbitrum, rust, stylus

I am attempting to replicate a solidity storage layout in stylus.

It includes a struct, and a list of that struct object:

```js
    struct Person {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }
    // uint256[] public anArray;
    Person[] public listOfPeople;
```

In stylus, how would I setup the `sol_storage!` macro for this?

```rust
sol_storage! {
    #[entrypoint]
    pub struct SimpleStorage {
        // What goes in here?
    }
}
```

---

*Bonus*

What would go in the `impl` to make a getter for this array?